# How to check if more than one column is empty or NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, operator-precedence

I'm trying to write a SELECT statement that will return all rows where two columns are either empty or NULL. Both columns need to be blank or NULL.

I've tried this query within PHPMyAdmin - however, it's still returning some rows where the column value for either is 'on'.

```
SELECT * 
        FROM product
        WHERE isstock IS NULL 
                   OR isstock = ''
        AND
        iscon IS NULL 
                   OR iscon = ''
```

Can anybody explain where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should organize your query with parenthesis:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product
WHERE (isstock IS NULL OR isstock = '')
  AND (iscon IS NULL OR iscon = '')
```

If we add the parenthesis to your original query as they are by default:

```
isstock IS NULL OR
(isstock = '' AND iscon IS NULL) OR
iscon = ''
```

So without the ()'s it means totally different.

In mysql you can do this as well:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product
WHERE
    ifnull(isstock,'') = '' 
   AND
    ifnull(iscon,'') = ''
```

Maybe this is a bit cleaner.